# Call to undefined function error in plugin

Tags: php, plugin-development, functions

I wrote a function inside a class that gets a user's country from the IP address...

```
function getcountry() {
    if (!class_exists('GeoIP')) {
    include_once("geoip.inc");
    }

    if (empty($_SERVER["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"])) {
        $ip_address = $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];
    } else {
        $ip_address = $_SERVER["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"];
    }

    $GeoIPv4_file = plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'data/GeoIPv4.dat';
    $GeoIPv6_file = plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'data/GeoIPv6.dat';

    if (!filter_var($ip_address, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP, FILTER_FLAG_IPV4) === FALSE) {     
        if ( is_readable ( $GeoIPv4_file ) ) 
        $gi = \LSMIGeoIP\geoip_open( $GeoIPv4_file, GEOIP_STANDARD );
        $user_country = \LSMIGeoIP\geoip_country_code_by_addr($gi, $ip_address);
        \LSMIGeoIP\geoip_close($gi);
    } elseif (!filter_var($ip_address, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP,FILTER_FLAG_IPV6) === FALSE) {
        if ( is_readable ( $GeoIPv6_file ) )
        $gi = \LSMIGeoIP\geoip_open( $GeoIPv6_file, GEOIP_STANDARD );
        $user_country = \LSMIGeoIP\geoip_country_code_by_addr($gi, $ip_address);
        \LSMIGeoIP\geoip_close($gi);
    } else {
        $user_country = "Can't locate IP: " . $ip_address;              
    }       
    return $user_country;
}
```

but calling the function within another function...

```
function set_visibility( $items, $menu, $args ) {
    $user_country = getcountry();
...
```

returns an error: `Call to undefined function getcountry()`

If I take the code inside the function and place it inside the other function, it successfully retrieves the user's country.

What's my noob mistake?

Comment: Try this: `$user_country = $this->getcountry();` (If the function `set_visibility` is within the same class).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try following while you get such error:

- Searched for the php file with the function definition in it.
  Verified that the file exists.
- Verified that the require (or include) statement for the above file
  exists in the page. Also, verified the absolute path in the
  require/include is correct.
- Verified that the filename is spelled correctly in the require
  statement.
- Echoed a word in the included file, to see if it has been properly
  included.
- Defined a separate function at the end of file, and called it. It
  worked too.

**Problem :**

- Your function is probably in a different namespace than the one
  you're calling it from.

**Solution :**

$this-> refers to a function that belongs to the class and is declared within the class, same thing applies for variables declared inside the class. Inside the class it's called $this->function(), If public outside the class it's called $theclass->function()